# Функция len() строки задача

Tags: python-3.x

1. Напишите программу, которая выводит длину введенной пользователем строки, а также первый, пятый и последний символ.

   ```
   a = input(str()) # Например слово Javascript 
   print(len(a), '=Общее количество символов')
   print(a[0], '=первый', a[4], '=пятый', a[-1], '=последний')
   ```

   Тут все понятно.
2. Не забудьте предусмотреть случай, когда длина строки составляет меньше пяти символов.

   ```
   a = input(str()) # Например слово Java
   print(len(a), '=Общее количество символов')
   print(a[0], '=первый', a[4], '=пятый', a[-1], '=последний')
   ```

   > IndexError: string index out of range

Вариант решения конструкцией :

```
a = input(str())  # Например слово Java
strlen = len(a)
print(strlen, '=Общее количество символов')
if strlen > 5:
    five_element = a[4]
else:
    five_element = 'Строка короче 5 символов'
print(a[0], '=первый', five_element, '=пятый', a[-1], '=последний')
```

Варианты? циклом? а можно обойтись без if?

Comment: Исправил, да это конструкция.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цикла у Вас нет, if - не цикл. У Вас проще, но можно так:

```
try
    print(a[0], a[-1], a[4])
except IndexError:
    print("Строка короче пяти символов")
```

Comment: Ваш пример не выведет первый и последний символ, если длина меньше 5 символов. А еще Ваш пример навел на мысль, что неплохо было бы обрабатывать случай, если строка пустая.

Comment: @Jenyay  это просто альтернатива if. Можно так все случаи обработать.